# Difference in two row values of the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a lab values table that I would like to query and get the difference between the last value and the most recent value if its >= 0.2. How do I go around doing that. Here is the query I have so far. Any help would be appreciated. Database is Oracle 10g. See screenshot for details.

```
SELECT DISTINCT VISITLAB.DATEOFENTRY, VISITLAB.LABVALUE, VISITLAB.CODE      
FROM(XCX.PATIENTVISIT PATIENTVISIT
       INNER JOIN
          XCX.MASTERPATIENT MASTERPATIENT
       ON (PATIENTVISIT.MASTERPATIENTID = MASTERPATIENT.MASTERPATIENTID))
   INNER JOIN
      XCX.VISITLAB VISITLAB
   ON (VISITLAB.MASTERPATIENTID = PATIENTVISIT.MASTERPATIENTID)
      AND (VISITLAB.VISITNUMBER = PATIENTVISIT.VISITNUMBER)  
WHERE     (MASTERPATIENT.MASTERPATIENTID = 'xxxxxxxx')
   AND (VISITLAB.CODE = 'UQN0')
   AND (PATIENTVISIT.DISCHARGEDATE IS NULL)
   AND (PATIENTVISIT.FACILITYCODE = 'x')
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it have to be the in the query? Can it be done in whatever is running the query/getting the data (ie. a programming language or Excel)? It's usually easier to do row comparisons after running the query since programming languages/Excel allow you to do things like `row#-1`.

Comment: Or did I misunderstand, do you just want the query to return the difference of those two values?

Comment: What constitutes "most recent" and "last". Is it by the Date of Entry?

Comment: @ Drackir - Yes, I want to query the difference and present it to health care provider to make decisions. @Tom H - we get lab results every morning. So they are by date of entry.

Comment: It is hard to read code which is entirely UPPER CASE.  At least COBOL has the excuse of being *really old* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the LAG anayltical function to retrieve a value in the previous row.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT VISITLAB.DATEOFENTRY, VISITLAB.LABVALUE, VISITLAB.CODE, 
    (LAG(VISITLAB.LABVALUE) over (order by VISITLAB.DATEOFENTRY) - VISITLAB.LABVALUE) as DIFF
FROM(XCX.PATIENTVISIT PATIENTVISIT
INNER JOIN
       XCX.MASTERPATIENT MASTERPATIENT
       ON (PATIENTVISIT.MASTERPATIENTID = MASTERPATIENT.MASTERPATIENTID))
INNER JOIN
       XCX.VISITLAB VISITLAB
       ON (VISITLAB.MASTERPATIENTID = PATIENTVISIT.MASTERPATIENTID)
       AND (VISITLAB.VISITNUMBER = PATIENTVISIT.VISITNUMBER)
WHERE (MASTERPATIENT.MASTERPATIENTID = 'xxxxxxxx')
AND (VISITLAB.CODE = 'UQN0')
AND (PATIENTVISIT.DISCHARGEDATE IS NULL)
AND (PATIENTVISIT.FACILITYCODE = 'x')
) INLINEVIEW
WHERE DIFF < .2
```

This isn't necessarily the answer you are looking for but it demonstrates how I can compute a derive a value for a column based on the value in a previous row.

Comment: This works great. I am seeing my difference as DIFF, but I am unable to set a criteria where I want only of DIFF is >=0.2. I dont want to see a trigger if the value is <0.2

Comment: I edited my answer above... You can take the query from an inline view and filter the results of the DIFF column of the inline view.

Comment: Works great for what I want to do with it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear if you need to compute these DIFFs across all LABVALUEs for a given CODE (e.g UQN0). If you're interested just in the last two ones as shown in the posted screenshot then a pure SQL without any analytic functions may also be used:

```
create table lab (
  code varchar2(10), 
  date_of_entry date, 
  lab_value number(10,2)
);
insert into lab values('UQN0', trunc(sysdate) - 3, 0.98);
insert into lab values('UQN0', trunc(sysdate) - 2, 0.85);
insert into lab values('UQN0', trunc(sysdate) - 1, 0.90);
insert into lab values('UQN0', trunc(sysdate), 0.64);
commit;
select * from lab;

with last_results as (
  select t.* from (
    select * from lab where code = 'UQN0' 
   order by date_of_entry desc
  ) t where rownum <= 2
)
select t1.*
from last_results t1, last_results t2 
  where t1.lab_value - t2.lab_value  >= 0.2;
```

If there's no concern for ensuring compatibility with other database servers then the LAG() function is clearly the way to go.